# "install" new config file

Tags: configuration, usb-modem, huawei

Hello I am a relatively new user and hope this is the right place to ask this question.  I am trying to get a Huawei 3g dongle to work.  I think I found the answer but I don't know how to implement these steps:

```
    #Install into /etc/usb_modeswitch.d
    #HuaweiE3531s-2
     TargetVendor=0x12d1
     TargetProduct=0x15ce
        "MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

How exactly do I get this config file into the directory usb_modeswitch.d?
Thanks for a helping a new but happy user of Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file `HuaweiE3531s-2.conf` in `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d` with this content:

```
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProduct=0x15ce 
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

Answer (score 3):

On my installations the directory `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d` does not exist by default, so it must be created first:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/usb_modeswitch.d
```

To create the file, you could use the simple text editor `nano` to achieve this, using the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/HuaweiE3531s-2.conf
```

This will open the editor, where you can type in those required lines.

```
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProduct=0x15ce 
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

When you're finished carefully typing those lines, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write and save the file. One word of warning however, the 'MessageContent' line should not have a double quote before it, as shown in your question, though the double quotes around the number string are correct.

Comment: No problem, please could you click on the little grey tick to the left of this answer? It marks this as the correct answer, and closes it off nicely.